# Papers Please Booth Upgrades

Tags: papers-please

I am aware that at the "end of day" screen one is supposed to be able to buy an upgrade for their booth allowing them to use the space bar to enter inspect mode and use the tab to toggle the stamp bar, however there is no instruction stating where to look to purchase the in-game upgrades. I have searched through the "end of day" screen trying to find the upgrades with no clue where they are. if you found them, don't simply tell me that I can buy them on the "end of day" screen, as I already know that (apologies if I sound rude), but instead explain how to get them at said screen.

Comment: The possibility of a housing upgrade will appear (seemingly) randomly at the end of day screen. Once at that screen, an option will pop up that will let you purchase the flat.

Comment: They are listed at the end of day, in red/grey text with a tickbox like food and heat. You can only get them after quite a few days into the story, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an underlying mechanic to make them appear, e.g. a number of successful processings, number of detainments or similar. It is worth researching though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The booth upgrades become available in the end of day screen on set days during the game. There's nothing special you need to do to trigger it, you just need to make sure you saved enough cash to pay for it!

Comment: An upgrade costs [5 credits](http://papersplease.wikia.com/wiki/Booth#Upgrades). You also get a notification at the "end of day" screen that an upgrade is available.